is there any possibility to build slivers lazily?
there is huge list of models
if I want to build them lazily I need to use SliverList.builder
Everything looks OK until I need to add sticky headers.
I have to use e.g. SliverMainAxisGroup like this
               CustomScrollView(
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: controller,
                    slivers: [
                      for (final section in _data)
                        SliverMainAxisGroup(
                          slivers: [
                            PinnedHeaderSliver(
                              child: Builder(
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return Container(
                                    height: 64,
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    color: Colors.red.withOpacity(1),
                                    child: Text('DATE HEADER'),
                                  );
                                }
                              ),
                            ),
                            SliverList.builder(
                              itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  title: Text(section.items[i].content),
                                );
                              },
                              itemCount: section.items.length,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                    ],
                  );

and
final _data = List.generate(
  500,
  (index) => Section(
    'Section $index',
    List.generate(
      100,
      (index) => Item('Item $index'),
    ),
  ),
);

final class Section {
  Section(
    this.title,
    this.items,
  );

  final List<Item> items;
  final String title;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Section{title: $title}';
  }
}

final class Item {
  Item(this.content);
  final String content;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Item{content: $content}';   
  }
}

The main a single issue here is - ALL that items builded NOT lazily, it builds whole sections with all items.
